# Accessing locally defined structure in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers, struct

I've defined a local structure called item. I'm attempting to sort the items in terms of one of the elements, "uprice". When I attempt to switch the elements in the two items after a hit in the sort, I get an odd error saying that my array a[] of struct item pointers does not actually contain struct items. Here is what I have for code and the error following it:

This is the first portion of the code where I define the bsort function and my struct:

```
void bsort(struct item* a[], int n);

struct item{
        int bcode;
        int pcode;
        float length;
        float width;
        int sheets;
        int scode;
        float price;
        float uprice;
};

struct item* list;
```

This is the second portion of the code where I implement my bsort function:

```
void bsort(struct item* a[], int n)
{
  int i, j, temp;

  for (i = 0 ; i < n-1; i++)
  {
    for (j = 0 ; j < n-i-1; j++)
    {
      if (a[j].uprice > a[j+1].uprice)
      {
        temp = a[j].bcode;
        a[j] = a[j+1].bcode;
        a[j+1].bcode = temp;

        //Switch each property of the array individually
      }


    }
  }
}
```

The error message referring to the code within bsort:

```
price2.c: In function ‘bsort’:
price2.c:54: error: request for member ‘bcode’ in something not a structure or union
price2.c:55: error: request for member ‘bcode’ in something not a structure or union
price2.c:56: error: request for member ‘bcode’ in something not a structure or union
```

etc...

Comment: Please post the exact error message.

Comment: You don't need to switch each property individually: you can assign the whole struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it declared, `a` is an array of pointers to `item`s.  That being the case, you'd need to dereference each `a[i]` properly:

```
      if (a[j]->uprice > a[j+1]->uprice)
      {
        temp = a[j]->bcode;
        a[j] = a[j+1]->bcode;
        a[j+1]->bcode = temp;

        //Switch each property of the array individually
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a[j].uprice
```

It's still a pointer.